# Local Install of capistrano

Tags: installation, local, rubygems

This question is specific to capistrano, but it's a general gem question too.

I have to download and then install gems - no remote connection available.

I went to github and downloaded capistrano as tarball.
I get the file thoughtbot-capistrano-d1229b2.tar.gz

To install do I now...
- rename the tarball with a .gem extension and run

```
gem install thoughtbot-capistrano-d1229b2.gem
```

- just untar it to my local gem directory?
- something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build the tarbal using whatever mechanism is provided, in the case of (capistrano-capistrano) this is jeweler, so you can probably do `rake gem:build` and have a gem you can install with `gem install ./capistrano-2.5.10.gem` - since you are using thoughtbot-capistrano… all bets are off, their fork is way out of date.